# Prove that there exists $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $|\alpha - \lambda| < \frac{1}{1000}$ and $T-\alpha I$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose V is finite dimensional, $\mathcal{T} \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$. Prove that there exists $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $|\alpha - \lambda| < \frac{1}{1000}$ and $T-\alpha I$ is invertible.

So I have seen a solution to this question on another site and I am not able to make sense of how it was even put together. This is the solution:

Let $\alpha_i\in\mathbb{F}$ such that:

$$\left|\alpha_i-\lambda\right| = \frac{1}{1000+i},\quad i=1,\cdots,\dim V+1.$$

These $\alpha_i$ exist and are different from each other since $\mathbb{F} =\mathbb{R} \ or \ \mathbb{C}$ Note that each operator on $V$ has at most dim V distinct eignevalues by 5.13. Hence there exists some $i\in\{1,2,\cdots,\dim V+1\}$ such that $\alpha_i$ is not an eigenvalue of T. Then by 5.6, $T-\alpha I$ is invertible.

**Questions:** How does this solution work? I understand that we have to create the $\alpha$, but how to illustrate that this works? I'm not sure how the bound was chosen and I don't get how invertiblity is shown. In essence I am lost.....

For Reference:

> **Theorem 5.6** Equivalent conditions to be an eigenvalue:
>   Suppose V is finite-dimensional, $T \in \mathcal{L}(V),$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}.$ Then the following are equivalent:
>
> (a) $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of T ;
>
> (b) $T-\lambda I$ is not injective;
>
> (c) $T- \lambda I$ is not surjective;
>
> (d)$T- \lambda I$ is not invertible
>
> **Theorem 5.13**: Number of eigenvalues
>   Suppose V is finite-dimensional. Then each operator on V has at most
>   dim V distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: There are only a finite number of $\alpha$ such that $T-\alpha I$ is not invertible. The ball $B(\lambda, {1 \over 1000})$ contains an infinite number of points.

Comment: A similar attempt for the same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2657159/144766.

Comment: @copper.hat I am working through Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler. I've never known or seen this result. Where would I be able to see a proof of this notion?

Comment: The link that @mechanodroid gave is my attempt at this problem dont worry i was not able to produce a proof until i thought very hard about this problem too keep going

Answer (score 0):

As long as $\alpha$ is not one of the finitely many eigenvalues of $T$, $T-\alpha I$ is invertible.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1030912)

Comment: Sure it provides an answer.  I assume the asker knows there are more than finitely many numbers with absolute value less than $\frac{1}{1000}$.

Comment: I assume I am allowed to answer a question without being so explicit as to insult everyone's intelligence.

Comment: @CMonsour unfortunately I do not really know this. I've heard and picked up mention of it, but never proved the result myself.